# How do I test an AWS Lex bot locally?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am currently building a very complex voice application for a client. I am using AWS Lex for intent resolution and then AWS Lambda + Node/Typescript to execute the conversation logic.

My current development flow is much slower than I would like because I cant test my code locally. Every time I make changes to my code (frequently), I have to redeploy the relevant Lambda function to AWS so that I can interact with the Lex APIs. As you can imagine, this makes testing new changes quite difficult.

This there a way to do this all locally so that I dont have to drive through Lex every time?

Note: I am using Lex for intent resolution only -- Lex is in no way driving the conversation flow or generating responses for the user -- Lex is simply telling me which intents are being mapped and what the respective slots are

Comment: Hi @key-hoffman, do you have any updates on this?

Comment: Did anyone figure this out?